# How to print all topics in HiveMQ Client? (MQTT)

Tags: java, mqtt, hivemq

Is there a way to print all of the topics that the HiveMQ broker has stored? I'd like to print out all topics that clients are connected to for testing purposes in a main class in HiveMQ Client. I've left links for the HiveMQ Client and Community (Broker).

HiveMQ:

https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-community-edition https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-mqtt-client

Code in my main class for the HiveMQ Client:

```
package com.main;

import java.util.UUID;

import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.MqttGlobalPublishFilter;
import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.datatypes.MqttQos;
import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.mqtt5.Mqtt5BlockingClient;
import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.mqtt5.Mqtt5BlockingClient.Mqtt5Publishes;
import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.mqtt5.Mqtt5Client;
import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.mqtt5.message.publish.Mqtt5Publish;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class Main {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());  // Creates a logger instance 


    public static void main(String[] args) {

                Mqtt5BlockingClient client1 = Mqtt5Client.builder()
            .identifier(UUID.randomUUID().toString()) // the unique identifier of the MQTT client. The ID is randomly generated between 
            .serverHost("localhost")  // the host name or IP address of the MQTT server. Kept it 0.0.0.0 for testing. localhost is default if not specified.
            .serverPort(1883)  // specifies the port of the server
            .buildBlocking();  // creates the client builder

            client1.connect();  // connects the client
            System.out.println("Client1 Connected");
            System.out.println(client1.toString());


            String testmessage = "How is it going!";
            byte[] messagebytesend = testmessage.getBytes();   // stores a message as a byte array to be used in the payload 

    try {  

        Mqtt5Publishes publishes = client1.publishes(MqttGlobalPublishFilter.ALL);  // creates a "publishes" instance thats used to queue incoming messages

            client1.subscribeWith()  // creates a subscription 
            .topicFilter("test1/#")  // filters to receive messages only on this topic (# = Multilevel wild card, + = single level wild card)
            .qos(MqttQos.AT_LEAST_ONCE)  // Sets the QoS to 2 (At least once) 
            .send(); 
            System.out.println("The client1 has subscribed");


            client1.publishWith()  // publishes the message to the subscribed topic 
            .topic("test/pancakes/topic")   // publishes to the specified topic
            .qos(MqttQos.AT_LEAST_ONCE)  
            .payload(messagebytesend)  // the contents of the message 
            .send();
            System.out.println("The client1 has published");


            Mqtt5Publish receivedMessage = publishes.receive(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS).get(); // receives the message using the "publishes" instance waiting up to 5 seconds                                                                          // .get() returns the object if available or throws a NoSuchElementException 


         byte[] tempdata = receivedMessage.getPayloadAsBytes();    // converts the "Optional" type message to a byte array 
         System.out.println();
         String getdata = new String(tempdata); // converts the byte array to a String 
         System.out.println(getdata);


    }

    catch (InterruptedException e) {    // Catches interruptions in the thread 
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "The thread was interrupted while waiting for a message to be received", e);
        }

    catch (NoSuchElementException e){
        System.out.println("There are no received messages");   // Handles when a publish instance has no messages 
    }

    client1.disconnect();  
    System.out.println("Client1 Disconnected");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to print all of the topics that the HiveMQ broker has
>   stored?

No.  There is no such thing in MQTT as "give me a list of all topics in a broker".

Your code can subscribe to all "active" topics but that does mean you will capture all of the topics unless you leave your code running 7/24 for months or years.

Simply change your subscription to the following:

```
client1.subscribeWith().topicFilter("#")
```

Now your code will get messages for all "active" topics that publishers are publishing to.  Be forewarned, your code may get thousands of messages per second and probably many of the messages are for the same topic. Hence, you will need to filter those out.

Comment: Ok but I'm curious if there is a way to print out all of the topics a specific client is subscribed to easily?

Comment: Not from a client perspective.